# qt_gui_cpp fails to build on Debian Jessie

Tags: catkin-make, ros-hydro, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've saw the same problem, posted a month ago, on debian sid, but I will post another question, because i can't copy all the failure log. I'm sorry if I'm wrong...

I'm using the latest version of catkin, qt_gui_cpp, python_qt_binding and pluginlib

- shiboken 1.2.1-2
- phyton-sip 4.15.3-1
- boost 1.54.0
- libqt4-dev  4:4.8.5+git121-g2a9ea11+dfsg1-2

---

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'qt_gui_cpp'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/dave/ros/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/dave/ros/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
[ 37%] Built target qt_gui_cpp
[ 40%] Running Shiboken generator for libqt_gui_cpp Python bindings...
[ 44%] Meta target for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
[ 51%] Built target libqt_gui_cpp_sip
** WARNING APIExtractor does not support the use of #include directives without passing either "<path/to/header.h>" or "./path/to/header.h", for example. Invalid use at /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:26.
** WARNING APIExtractor does not support the use of #include directives without passing either "<path/to/header.h>" or "./path/to/header.h", for example. Invalid use at /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:53.
** WARNING scope not found for symbol:boost::detail::esft2_deleter_wrapper::get_deleter<D>
Generating class model...                    [WARNING]
        Unable to decide type of property: 'Qt::CursorMoveStyle' in class 'QLineEdit'
        enum 'QFont::HintingPreference' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        Unable to decide type of property: 'SoftKeyRole' in class 'QAction'
        Unable to decide type of property: 'Priority' in class 'QAction'
        enum 'QStyle::RequestSoftwareInputPanel' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QFile::FileHandleFlag' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QXmlStreamReader::ReadElementTextBehaviour' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QLocale::CurrencySymbolFormat' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QAction::SoftKeyRole' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QLocale::Script' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        Unable to decide type of property: 'QEasingCurve' in class 'QTimeLine'
        enum 'QGraphicsItem::PanelModality' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QLocale::QuotationStyle' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QDataStream::FloatingPointPrecision' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QTextDocument::Stacks' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        Unable to decide type of property: 'Qt::InputMethodHints' in class 'QWidget'
        enum 'QPainter::PixmapFragmentHint' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QAction::Priority' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QTextBlockFormat::LineHeightTypes' does not have a type entry or is not an enum


Generating enum model...                     [WARNING]
        enum 'SP_CustomTabVideos' does not have a type entry or is not an enum


Generating namespace model...                [WARNING]
        enum 'Qt::GestureState' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::CursorMoveStyle' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::TouchPointState' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::GestureFlag' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::TileRule' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::NavigationMode' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::AnchorPoint' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::GestureType' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::CoordinateSystem' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'QtConcurrent::ThreadFunctionResult' does not have a type entry or is not an enum
        enum 'Qt::InputMethodHint' does not have a type entry or is not an enum


Resolving typedefs...                        [OK]
Fixing class inheritance...                  [WARNING]
        class not found for setup inheritance 'QGraphicsObject'
        class 'QGraphicsWidget' inherits from unknown base class 'QGraphicsObject'
        class 'QGraphicsTextItem' inherits from unknown base class 'QGraphicsObject'


Detecting inconsistencies in class model...  [OK]
[OK]
        enum 'QX11EmbedContainer::Error' is specified in typesystem, but not declared
        enum 'QPixmap::ShareMode' is specified in typesystem, but not declared
        type 'QGenericArgument' is specified in typesystem, but not defined. This could potentially lead to compilation errors.
        enum 'QMetaObject::Call' is specified in typesystem, but not declared
        type 'QPyTextObject' is specified in typesystem, but not defined. This could potentially lead to compilation errors.
        type 'QX11Info' is specified in typesystem, but not defined. This could potentially lead to compilation errors.
        enum 'QX11EmbedWidget::Error' is specified in typesystem, but not declared
        type 'QMetaObject' is specified in typesystem, but not defined. This could potentially lead to compilation errors.
        type 'QX11EmbedContainer' is specified in typesystem, but not defined. This could potentially lead to compilation errors.
        type 'QGenericReturnArgument' is specified in typesystem, but not defined. This could potentially lead to compilation errors.
        type 'QX11EmbedWidget' is specified in typesystem, but not defined. This could potentially lead to compilation errors.


Segmentation fault
make[2]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/libqt_gui_cpp_shiboken/libqt_gui_cpp_shiboken_module_wrapper.cpp] Error 139
make[1]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeFiles/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'qt_gui_cpp': 
  Command '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/dave/ros/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp && /opt/ros/hydro/env.sh make -j4 -l4
```

---

thanks in advance for reading my question...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99351/qt_gui_cpp-fails-to-build-on-debian-jessie/) by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) on 2013-11-10**:
I've forgot to say that this was an issue already in the beginning of september with groovy, I've solved updating shiboken package. But now I've the same package as Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

a workaround to not build PySide bindings has been posted here:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/issues/35#issuecomment-28527836

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2014-01-17**:
For posterity: the solution is to remove libshiboken. This forces the installer to use an alternative library. The command to be used is "sudo apt-get remove libshiboken*". Hopefully there's nothing else on your system that depends on it.  This also fixes the same failure in Ubuntu 13.10.